# Jenkins plugin/feature to rerun failed tests for svn builds

Tags: ant, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I was searching for a jenkins plugin to re-run only the failed tests for a specified number of times. Came across [Flaky test handler plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flaky+Test+Handler+Plugin). But this plugin is only for maven projects.

Is there a similar plugin for ant projects?